# Data Management API's - Issues tag not present

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I'm using Data Management API's to get projects info [API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-hub_id-projects-GET/). In some cases hubs/:hub_id/projects API doesn't returns issues tag into relationships tag.

[image: Here KO]

[image: Here OK]

If I go in BIM360's project issues are presents.

[image: BIM360 project's issues]

Is there a particular reason for this lack?

TIA
Alder

Comment: Hi Alder,
Only Issue is missed or any others (like submittal, rfi )are also missed?
In addition, is that a newly created project by code? i.e. probably this project has not activated Document Management Module at all.

Comment: @varunpatil, only hub, rootFolder and topFolders are presents. Is not a project created by code. The strange thing is that now, after administrator grant "Full Control” as “Permission Level” on the project, I can see it! But on the other projects I don't have "Full Control" (only "View All")... And "issueContainerId" is present...

Comment: Yes, you do need permission. So, the problem is resolved now?